# What is the quickest way to write lots of data to TXT file in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, text

o, I'm extracting lots of data from an OpenVMS RDB Oracle database with a Python script.

On "hand-made" profiling, 3/4 of the time is taken writing down the data to the TXT file.

```py
print >> outputFile, T00_EXTPLANTRA_STRUCTS.setStruct(parFormat).build(hyperContainer)
```

This is the specific line that prints out the data, which takes 3/4 of the execution time. 
T00_EXTPLANTRA_STRUCTS.py is an external file containing the data structures (Which .setStruct() defines), and the hyperContainer is a Container from "Construct" library that contains data.

It takes almost five minutes to extract the whole file. I'd really like to learn if there is a way to write TXT data faster than this.

I already optimized the rest of the code especially DB transactions, it's just the writing operation that's taking a long time to execute.

The data to write looks like this, with 167.000 lines of this kind. (I hid the actual data with "X")

```
XX;XXXXX;X;>;XXXXX;XXXX;XXXXXXXXXXXXXX            ;XXX;   ;XXX; ;
```

Lots of thanks for anyone spending any time on this.

Comment: post the contents of the python files. I suspect thats where the bulk of time is spent because writing to a text file is trivial

Comment: writing 167k lines containing your above string takes my computer ~0.1 seconds, the issue is therefore in the rest of your code...

Comment: thanks for the answers, I found the problem. it was coming from the Construct library method ".build()" which I roughly rewrote. Now it's working like a charm, and writing time has been divided by 3.
I think that was coming from the Container + Build usage together, now I only use dictionnaries to structure my data.

FYI, new code writes 1M500 lines in 3 seconds, I "benchmarked" it to see the difference.